# How to add a condition for the user's connection?

Tags: react-native, redirect, conditional-statements

I want to add to this code the condition: if the user is connected, he goes directly to BottomTabNavigator (which is the opening of the application) and otherwise he goes in the Authentication file which will allow him to either connect or register. How can I do this ?
Usually I used

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import BottomTabNavigator from "./Navigation/TabNavigator";


const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <BottomTabNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App
```

Usually in a class component I used this, but I don't know how to do with the new syntax:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isFirstConnection: true,
      status: 0,
      fontLoaded: false
    };
  }

  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    let lang = await retrieveAppLang();
    let isConnected = await userSessionActive();

    if (lang.length == 2) {
      i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
    }

    if (isConnected === true && this.props && this.props.navigation) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("TabBar");
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      FunctionLH: require("./assets/fonts/FunctionLH-Light.ttf")
    });

    const data = await this.performTimeConsumingTask();
    if (data !== null) {
      this.setState({
        isFirstConnection: false,
        status: 1,
        fontLoaded: true,
      });
    }
  }

  performTimeConsumingTask = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("result");
      }, 750)
    );
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.status == 1) {
      if (this.state.isFirstConnection && this.state.fontLoaded) {
        return <SplashScreen />;
      } else {
        return <Navigation screenProps={'Authentication'} />;
      }
    }

    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("./assets/images/background.jpg")}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <View style={[styles2.container, styles2.containerCentered]}>
          <StatusBar hidden={true} />
          <View style={styles2.subContainer}>
            <Image
              style={styles2.logo}
              source={require("./assets/images/logo.png")}
            />
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#43300E" />
            <Text>{i18n.t("app.loading") + "..."}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}}
```

the 'isConnected' is on a file "myPreferences"

```
export async function userSessionActive() {
  let userAuthorizationCode = await retrieveProfileAuthorizationCode();
  let userUserId = await retrieveProfileUserId();
  let userEmail = await retrieveProfileLogin();
  let is_connected = false;

  if (userAuthorizationCode != '' && userUserId !== null && parseInt(userUserId) > 0 && userEmail != '') {
    is_connected = true;
  }

  return is_connected;
}
```

I thought doing something like this but it's not working :

```
function App(userSessionActive) {
  const isConnected = userSessionActive.isConnected;
  if (isConnected) {
    return <NavigationContainer>
              <BottomTabNavigator />
           </NavigationContainer>;
  }
  return <StackNavigator screenProps={'Authentication'}/>;
}

export default App
```

Comment: Did the class component work ? and do you update the isConnected from the authentication screen ?

Comment: Yes it works. The isConnected comes from a file myPreferences where I have every function calling the api or the user information (I edited my post to show you the detail) :)

Comment: nothing wrong with using class component, and only thing is you will have to get rid of the componentwillmount, you will have to use hooks

Comment: Alright I thought I couldn't go on with class components... I'll have to check the hooks I don't really know how to use it correctly...

Comment: If things are working as expected no need to change anything else just remove the componentWillMount

Comment: Alright thanks. The problem I get right now is with : "  StackNavigator screenProps={'Authentication'} "  it returns an error : Element type is invalid but it seems that the rest of the behaviour of the screen is ok.

Comment: are these custom components?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224520/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-kimako).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I resolved the bug of APP.js now I have aproblem with the redirected screen which is Authentication bu I go on, I will get how to resolve it.